# HTML to PDF Node not working

Tags: flowgear

This is the error I get:

"Could not get the metafile from HTML string. Could not initialize the html converter object.Request failed.."

It also takes very long to process, always more than 20 seconds.

The HTML code is below:

```
<html><div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>
        GST/HST number
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    some #
</div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">
  <label>
        Business name
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    some company
</div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">
  <label>
    Transaction date
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    some date
</div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">
  <label>
        Result
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    GST/HST number registered on this transaction date.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a body tag and closing off the html tag?

Comment: Haven't tried that, will try now.

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at this, if you add html and body tags and make sure that the rest of the HTML is valid (there's an unclosed div as well), this works.

That Node does require you to use a DropPoint as well though.